# Pandas : Get row from an ID which is a split of a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` that contains a list of filename.

Here is an example :

```
print(df)

>>
+---------+---------+
|       ID|    Field|
+---------+---------+
|  AAA.png|        X|
|  BBB.jpg|        Y|
|  CCC.png|        Z|
+---------+---------+
```

From a given `ID`, which is the filename without the extension, I want to retrieve the value of the column `Field`.

For example, for `my_id = BBB`, I want to get the value `Y`.

To so, I tried the following thing :

```
my_id = BBB
field_value = df[df["ID"].str.split('.')[0] == my_id]["Field"]
```

But I get the error `KeyError: False`. I understand why I have this error but I don't know how I can do that in an other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - output is `Series`:

```
field_value = df.loc[df["ID"].str.split('.').str[0] == my_id, "Field"]
```

And then for first value use `next` with `iter`:

```
first val = next(iter(field_value), 'no match')
```

If need all matched values in list:

```
L = field_value.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
my_id="BBB"
field_values = df.loc[df["ID"].str.contains(my_id), "Field"]
print(field_values)
```

It can return multiple values as you can see. Also it is bullet prof for file names starting with `.`, like `.AAA.png`.

---

```
        ID Field
0  AAA.png     X
1  BBB.jpg     Y
2  CCC.png     Z
3  BBB.png     K
1    Y
3    K
Name: Field, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `os.path.splitext`

**Ex:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["AAA.png", "BBB.png", "CCC.png"],
                   "Field": ["X", "Y", "Z"]})

my_id = "BBB"
mask = df["ID"].apply(os.path.splitext).str[0] == my_id
print(df[mask]["Field"])
```

**Output:**

```
1    Y
Name: Field, dtype: object
```